# How to group rows in excel with certain values in a neighboring column?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to learn the VBA code to group cells that only include certain values. I have numerous cities that have an origin and destination listed under the city. I would like to summarize the performance of the cities.

Each city may have several origin and destinations under them. The count varies. I have created an excel function in another column that identifies a city and refers to it as "TRUE" while it refers to an O&D as "FALSES".

Can someone provide me with the VBA code to group the FALSES, so that only the TRUES show?

Then I can have good subtotal information for the True markets.

Comment: I am thinking auto filter on your key would be a good idea in vba: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel

Comment: Pivottable maybe?